# How to get permalink for a RAW file in private repo on github?

Tags: authentication, github, github-api

I am searching google for almost 2 hours and didn't find anything useful. I need to get permalink to RAW file from my private repository. I mean a link that I can open and view in my browser, just like normal RAW file in public repo.

I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66124841/permalink-to-raw-file-in-github-private-repo), it says I can do that with https://acces_token@raw.githubusercontent.com/acc/repo/branch/file.name but that doesn't work for me. I tried with both fine-grained token and classic one with full permissions and none of them worked. All I had got was "404: Not Found" every time. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I have found this solution https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/23845 Hope it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the link looks for one of my files. Does this work for you?

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<username>/<repo_name>/<branch>/path/to/file.txt?token=<access_token>
```

Comment: Well this is link created automatically, though it only works for few days, after that it points to 404: Not Found. Changing <access_token> to one of my generated tokens doesn't work.