# getting error 404: Not Found when accessing a file from private repo

Tags: github, cdn, private, repo

trying to access a file from a private github repo using [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66124841/permalink-to-raw-file-in-github-private-repo) method... but everytime i try to access it i get 404 errors.

downloading the file directly through github's cdn